# What is the purpose of voting for questions on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we vote on questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37199/why-do-we-vote-on-questions)

I get why you vote on answers, but what is the purpose of voting for questions?  Perhaps there is some documentation somewhere that explains it.  If anyone could shed some light on this it would be most appreciated.

Comment: @Michael Thanks.  Not sure why I switched that.  Sorry.

Comment: @jonsca: I suspect you stepped over an (unlogged) edit that iamkrillin made just after he posted this question. Nothing you could have done, if this is the case. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make).

Comment: @Michael Ah, that makes me feel a bit better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that people are rewarded for (and therefore encouraged to) post good questions, and also so they attract good answers for interesting and well-stated problems.  None of the answerers want to deal with horrid questions all the time, I promise you.