# What are the main reasons for a question being voted down?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What purpose does downvoting questions serve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve)

I've been using SO for a while now, and I've noticed that some questions get voted down without people saying *why* they vote down.

My understanding for when one should vote down, is:

- The question is offtopic (probably the most common closing reason)
- The question lacks information
- The question is subjective and argumentative

Besides these reasons, there seems to be a hundred other reasons why people see the urge to vote down. 
The question is, ***why*** would someone vote down a question, probably wanting to make future questions better, and not comment on it?

Comment: An important distinction, were _any_ voted down on MSO? The ecosystem here is a bit different.

Comment: "In which case commenting on it would still help" and yet they disagree. You can't use technology to force a social change. Sadly.

Comment: Please edit your question to include links to the posts that were downvoted -- we may be able to give you more direct guidance than simply answering the question posed here.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Actually, I didn't want to include any links, to keep the question objective...

Comment: Well, downvotes (and voting in general) is inherently subjective. I understand abstracting the question here (although we could surely say this topic has been covered on Meta before), but I think you'd get better feedback by citing specific examples.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Indeed this topic existed before on MSO, but I guess bringing it on just once again doesn't hurt...

Comment: See: [What purpose does downvoting questions serve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve) and [Why is down-voting a question important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16006/why-is-down-voting-a-question-important) - and FWIW, I don't down-vote to make future questions better, **I down-vote to let other readers know that the post I'm voting on is a waste of their time.**

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: -1 You wrote *Indeed this topic existed before on MSO, but I guess bringing it on just once again doesn't hurt*

Comment: @Alejandro True. But it got closed anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement to explain a vote.

Period.

Every day, hundreds of truly awful questions arrive on the sites. Some people take the time to downvote them. A very few <del>take</del>waste the additional time to explain. It's not like it's genetic engineering to tell what makes a good or bad question. Just reading the FAQ and paying some tiny bit of attention to it will pretty nearly guarantee you a positive vote count.

While there are, of course, some drive-by downvotes of innocent questions, there are far more 'pity upvoters' of downvoted questions, however awful. So you really have to work hard to make a question so poor that it ends with a net negative tally.

Comment: I forgot to add that I was talking about quite wellformed questions, questions where you can see that the author took the time to write a good question. It's just my opinion, and I always add a comment when I don't agree with a question or an answer.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: so, uh... why are you down-voting good questions?

Comment: @Shog9 What are you talking about?

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: you wrote that you were talking about good questions, and that you always add a comment when you down-vote. But by limiting the scope to questions *you already like*, you're implying that you down-vote questions you don't think are bad.

Comment: @Shog9 I rarely vote down or up, how does this relate to anything? I don't browse SO daily either, so I can hardly decide when a question is 'good' or 'bad' - asking in general is a good thing, IMHO.

Comment: @neb: so then what was the point of your first comment on this answer?

Comment: @Shog9 It seemed like @Rosinante was referering to MSO, instead of SO. And I can understand that some questions on MSO tend to be not exactly perfect - it was merely a misunderstanding from my side.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar I think Rosinante was indeed referring to SO proper, not Meta.

Comment: @Pekka so it was nothing but a misunderstanding. :-)

Comment: @nebukadnezzar yeah. And I wholeheartedly agree - there simply is too much bad content coming in for there to be time to leave a comment, especially if there is strong indication that it's going to be useless anyway because the OP doesn't want to learn anything.

Comment: @Pekka I see. But I can assure you that I don't ignore comments I receive - but as you said, this seems to count only for a minority of people.

Comment: @neb it's SO I'm talking about. As always around here, if you can't link to it, it never happened. If you have a population of good questions that ended up negative, post links.

Comment: @Rosinante See my comments to the original question. The linked question doesn't include links either, and I'm not going to add any.

Comment: @nebu: your inability to add to what's already been discussed here is why this was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Shog9 It's not an inability, since i'm deliberately not adding links. But feel free to put it in whatever way that makes you feel comfortable about it.

Comment: @neb: I was trying to be kind by not writing "stubborn unwillingness" - but have it your way.

Comment: @Shog9 And I politely told you that I deliberately didn't include any links. Yes indeed, have it your way.

Comment: @neb mene mene tekel upharsin.

Comment: So is this pointless comment-based argumentation becoming a overly verbose and pseudocryptic, but yet rather obvious flamefest?

Answer (score 1):

> An important distinction, were any
>   voted down on MSO? The ecosystem here
>   is a bit different. – drachenstern

drachenstern already said this, but I thought it was important enough to get an answer:

On MetaStackOverflow, sometimes all a downvotes means is "I don't aggree", "I don't think this is a good idea", or even "I don't like you".  Conversely, sometimes (On MSO) all an upvote means is "I aggree", "I *do* think this is a good idea", or even(yes, even this) "I like you".

Comment: "I don't like you" and "I like you" seem to be fairly common reasons on SO ;-). Not saying how this affects downvotes or upvotes, but I figure you can imagine what I mean.

Comment: @neb: Those are not valid or common reasons anywhere.  On Stack Overflow an up/downvote means "this is [not] useful/correct".  On Meta it means "I agree/disagree".  I seriously doubt "I don't like you" is anywhere near as common as you seem to believe.

Comment: @Aarobot On a second thought, I'll have to agree - I meant to say it's one of many reasons - Sorry for implying.

Answer (score -6):

There's a lot of petty retaliation here, too. If someone dislikes an answer, they'll go and vote everything a user did down. Sometimes it has nothing to do with a question.

Comment: The fact that this got voted -2 is a clear indication of "petty retaliation"

Comment: @Thrillsciense I've got to agree with you here - I see no reason either to vote down here.

Comment: Petty retaliation? You accuse the *entire userbase* of vote-abuse, with no proof and in ignorance of the systems and policies in place to restrict such behavior, and the only reason you can think of for being down-voted is that folks hate you for *something else* you wrote?

Comment: You really need to define "a lot."  Yes, it happens, but compared to legitimate downvoting of bad questions we get very few reports of retaliatory downvoting.

Comment: @Shog9 I doubt he meant the ***whole*** userbase.

Comment: I'm sure there's a little bit of petty retaliation.  There are also a lot of terrible answers.  This is one of them.

Comment: @thrillscience maybe you want to back your claim up with some actual data.

Comment: @neb: fair enough - he only fingered every user who has ever disliked an answer posted by another user.

Comment: @thrillscience: Well, you would know about petty retaliation. You did exactly that with me, after I asked you to clarify what "does not work" meant (not that -40 points matters to me). But that's the only time it happened to me, so your claim that there is "a lot" seems doubtful.

Comment: @Lennart don't worry, those upvotes will be cancelled within 24 hours by the [anomaly detection system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim). If they don't, E-Mail team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Pekka: Nice to know. (Although as mentioned 40 point here or there is rather irrelevant).