# Why downvote questions posted by new users when their rep won't be affected?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What purpose does downvoting questions serve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve)

Why bother, and what's the point, behind downvoting questions posted by new users who won't see any negative rep repercussions?

Being on only 1 rep, they stand to lose no rep at all from being downvoted.

Shouldn't we just vote to close instead?

Comment: Did I miss the "today is make everything community wiki day" memo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's more purpose to downvoting than simply affecting the reputation of the user -- otherwise why bother voting on community wiki questions and answers? It affects the sort order in search results, such as when searching within a tag.