# How much bias is there in voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, bias

There seem to be two large possible sources of bias, that is, things which could cause different voting on identical answers:

- we could be more likely to upvote answers for high-rep users, especially ones with familiar names
- we could be more likely to upvote answers with high scores, and downvote answers with low (negative) scores (even assuming that all answers fit on the screen)

Of course, high-rep users are generally likely to write answers worth upvoting, and high-scoring answers are often worth a vote. But humans are not generally perfectly rational; I assume there is bias. **Have there ever been attempts to quantify the effect here?** (Please try to avoid answers based on opinion and anecdote.)

Edit: I tried to write this as neutrally as possible. I am not arguing that Stack Exchange is fundamentally broken, or that you personally are a biased voter and therefore a bad person. I am not complaining about any perceived unfair voting. I think high-reputation users deserve their reputation. I like these sites. I'm just curious, within this context, how large of an effect cognitive biases have.

Another edit: I'm curious about the downvoting. I know it's different on meta, and I'm not offended, but since the core idea of the question is "is there any data about this effect" I'm wondering how people disagree - simply because it's hard to measure, or you believe that it would be bad for us to even know the answer? I'm happy to try to improve the question.

Comment: I'm *sure* this is a duplicate... anyone know offhand what a good candidate is?

Comment: @TheUnhandledException: I was sure too, and I couldn't find one quickly. Hopefully someone else is better at searching than me.

Comment: Related: [The Problem with Reputation: Does High Reputation Attract Too Many 'Up-Votes'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes)

Comment: Basic cognitive biases lead to these behaviors. Unfortunately you're not going to remove them so long as the names and vote counts remain public, and removing those would yield more damage than these biases.

Comment: @BenBrocka: I know *why* these things happen, and I'm not trying to fix it; I'm asking if we know how bad it is, and attempted to phrase the question in as neutral a way as possible.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39884/59303) (not mine) is the kind of experiment I'd like to see run.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, I was envisioning the same sort of thing, except say, taking .1% of the viewers of a given question, and serving them a page with modified votes (or usernames/avatars, or reputations).

Comment: *"Please try to avoid answers based on opinion and anecdote."* Given that no one but the team has access to attributed voting histories *except* their own there are very nearly no other answers available.

Comment: @ChrisF while A/B tests are fun the answer seems fairly obvious, and we have no reasonable action to take regardless of the outcome of the test. The two solutions to the two potential problems (A: Users are more likely to upvote the first question they read, B: Users are more likely to upvote the question of high rep users) would be to remove the sort-by-upvote and remove the rep-count, which IMO are both opposed to the intent of the site's mission of promoting authoritative answers.

Comment: @BenBrocka - true, but unless you know if reputation (or indeed identity) affects voting behaviour and by how much you can't make a proper decision.

Comment: @dmckee: Well, maybe someone extremely enterprising out there has been scraping pages and doing their own study. Failing that, I'm sure the team has considered it, and figured perhaps might be willing to at least say "we don't think it's a large enough problem to worry about", and even data about size of bias in similar situations could be informative.

Comment: Sure there is bias.

Comment: Jefromi - but how could an enterprising screen scraper find out any more about this than we can with access to the data explorer? Voting data isn't available; hence we can't know for sure how much bias there is. Hell, we couldn't even know if we *had* the voting data. Maybe high-rep users get so many votes solely because their answers are so great? (I don't believe that, but it's a possibility.) The only way to find out would be an experiment like @Chris pointed to

Comment: @ChrisF my point was more that there is no proper decision to be made, at least I certainly can't imagine any solutions to this problem that wouldn't harm the community and authority aspects of the site significantly. Take away rep/gamification and not only do answers lose their "weight" (arguably good or bad) but many users also lose the extrinsic benefit and lose a lot of reason to use the site (very bad)

Comment: @Pekka: You can't do anything about high-rep users, but you could try to look at bandwagon effects, since you could attempt to measure the chance that a view of the question resulted in a vote for each given answer. It'd be difficult, but who knows, there are a lot of crazy people out there.

Comment: @BenBrocka: There are ways to address issues like this besides entirely destroying voting mechanics, but I did not intend that to be within the scope of the question.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting idea. It would require SE publishing times of views and times of votes. Maybe as an "Academic data dump"? That 
*would* be cool.

Comment: @Pekka: I said it'd be difficult because I was thinking of the brute force method: scrape the same questions repeatedly and watch their view and vote counts. But yes, that'd be very cool.

Comment: Why do rich people have all the money?

Comment: It is worth examining the discussions around [Is there an actual “pity” or “sympathy” upvote problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93356/2509) to get an idea how hard and contentious it can be to work this stuff out.

Comment: @dmckee true, I hadn't considered the "pity" effect too; I often vote up a fair to good answer if it's someone with a low rep count as well.

Comment: @Pekka: A potential way to measure effects of high rep without actually serving people fake pages, though I suspect there's not enough data to overcome noise: compare voting history of answers posted by low-rep users which were last edited by a high-rep user to that of answers which were edited by a high-rep user in the past, but then subsequently edited by the original user again.

Comment: There's a very [detailed analysis](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/does-jon-skeet-have-mental-powers-that-make-us-upvote-his-answers-the-effect-of-reputation-on-upvotes/) about this topic on the Cross Validated (statistics StackExchange) blog that may interest you as well.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Even though it doesn't cover everything, that's more of an answer than anything else that's been posted. I'd upvote it if you posted it as one.

Comment: @jefromi Done =)  I'm somewhat new to meta, so I'm more hesitant about posting than I would be on SO.

Comment: @jadarnel27 very nice stuff

Answer (score 7):

[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (the statistics StackExchange site) has a great blog post on this topic:

[Does Jon Skeet have mental powers that make us upvote his answers? (The effect of reputation on upvotes)](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/does-jon-skeet-have-mental-powers-that-make-us-upvote-his-answers-the-effect-of-reputation-on-upvotes/).

There is a lot of detail in that post (much of which I do not fully understand), but the tl;dr version is this

> But it appears on average these high rep users always had a high score
>   per answer, even before they gathered a high reputation.

As [that guy with the palindromic name answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115490/168428), there is always human, mental / emotional bias that goes into voting (probably unconcscious in many cases); but, according to the numbers, it is not statistically significant.

Comment: +1: I much appreciate the link to the analysis, though I'm not sure I agree with the conclusions. (Score per view, or per post age, might show very different results.)

Comment: I just figured out another way to test this. Have Jon Skeet open another account, lets call it Teeks Noj, and see if simultaneously answer a question with both accounts, randomly deciding which one gets momentarily posted first. Also keep the wording the same. Then see which get upvoted more.

Comment: @puk That would just result in Jon Skeet getting suspended for using sock-puppet accounts ;-)  And *then* where would we be!

Comment: @jadarnel27 Jon Skeet is just as likely to be suspended as the president is to get a ticket for J-walking

Answer (score 7):

Okay, here's a plot. I am quite aware that this is not a perfect measurement, but it is so strikingly different from [the plots](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/does-jon-skeet-have-mental-powers-that-make-us-upvote-his-answers-the-effect-of-reputation-on-upvotes/) linked to in [jadarnel27's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115493/133299) that I feel it is worth seeing.

I took Jon Skeet's answers, calculated score *per question view*, and averaged over all posts from each day to reduce scatter.

[image: jon-skeet-votes-per-view]

So making the reasonable assumption that Jon Skeet mostly gets upvotes, then we can conclude that people have been far more likely to upvote Jon Skeet's newer answers than his older ones. I don't want to leap to any conclusions about how much of this effect is reputation-based - I'm sure his post quality and speed have improved too - but we certainly can't say that the data demonstrates that this is a statistically insignificant effect, as claimed on Cross Validated. (Side note: that's quite an upturn earlier this year.)

For good measure, here's a similar plot, with score *per post age in days* instead:

[image]

Comment: Interesting data; but I don't think it's meaningful without some solid stats showing the *overall* data, too. That is: How do we know that people *in general* aren't voting more often per post view/post age today than two years ago?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: +1, yes, that's one of the limitations. I posted this with two primary goals: demonstrating that the Cross Validated analysis wasn't really measuring the right thing, and providing a bar for further answers to hopefully exceed. I've never used the data explorer before, and this took very little time. I'm sure someone with more spare time and more experience could do better, and inform us all.

Comment: I would be interested to see the same graphs for my answers: I answer posts which are usually more than 10 minutes old, on less popular tags, for users who generally don't even have enough rep to vote(!).

Comment: Jon is, well, Jon. This is a nice approach, but it might be more convincing if you did it for users of, say, 50k (maybe a subset as that will be a lot of data).

Comment: is it possible to regenerate those plots today in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't vote for people based on their reputation. However, I have found that I am more inclined to upvote an answer that has a dozen or more upvotes than one with zero or one. This might mean that it is a great question. It might also mean that it was the first question =P

A good test would be to go through a couple dozen answers and see how well votes correlate with post order.

Answer (score 0):

**A LOT**

There is a lot of bias.

People assume that since I have almost 30,000 reputation on Stack Overflow that I must know what I am doing and they upvote my answers and ask me questions in chat.

When I do get stuff wrong, they say things like:

> How did you get all that rep if you know **nothing**?

Reputation has nothing to do with a user's knowledge of any subject, it is just how much time they have used this (or any other) site, or their ability to google faster than other users.

```
Reputation != knowledge;
```

### In conclusion:

Yes, voting is biased. But it is not always the best thing to base votes on.

Comment: I have >30k rep on SO, and I'm sure there's bias in upvoting my answers. *But I have no idea how much*, and that's the point of the question. An anecdotal "a lot", while probably true, isn't terribly informative.

Comment: Rep doesn't equal knowledge but it typically correlates with one's ability to share useful knowledge and it is inherently a measure of authority.

Comment: I sometimes wonder whether people are  just geniuses or whether they google the stuff. For example, I'll ask which Michelin tire I should use on my vespa, and then 30 seconds later someone has a detailed response describing the chemical composition of Michelin tire TX-3450 right down to the string theory, and why tire TX-3550 is actually not optimal.

Comment: Funny, when I see similar/identical answers from both high and low rep users, I usually +1 the "little guy"