# Easy upvoting for more knowledged users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

I'm fairly new to the Stack Overflow community. Searching trough some questions, I very often recognize the following:

A few people giving similar answers aren't upvoted, but that one, which has a big lead in reputation, gets the points. No matter, if he answered more or less precisely, or if he was the first or last one answering.

Same with questioning: The most new questions upvoted came from high-reputation users, although I can not see that questions to be more constructive then others.

Is there any possibility to make this more equal? It seems to me, reputation grants an upvote sometimes.

Comment: How would you make it more equal?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115368/how-much-bias-is-there-in-voting, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/515/153020

Comment: I dont think anyone upvote because answer is give by 50k or 100k ....

Comment: In my experience, there usually is still a quality aspect to it. The content might be similar, but higher-rep users often just are that bit better at explaining the situation. Or perhaps they were there first. I won't say there is not a slight reputation influence, but I'm not sure if there is anything inherently problematic.

Comment: Can you show some actual real-world examples where two or more answers are identical in quality, were given at more or less the same time, but the high-rep user gained significantly more upvotes? While there is a certain inherent bias towards trusting what a high-rep user says, I think you will find that the high-rep user often also knows how to phrase things so everyone understands them, how to format their answers so that they look nice, etc.

Comment: I am guessing you came across some of the older questions. Do you think that the large number of votes could probably be a cause of the high-rep? 50 upvotes is a direct 500 rep from a single answer. Add that up from many and voila, 10k+ . Also, if you did come across the old questions, then one of the reasons that they have so many votes is because of the timeframe for which they have been up.

Comment: I do not observe this behaviour.