# Suspicious upvotes on that user

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, serial-voting

I've came across the posts of a user from review queue.

Those are terribly bad questions, taken out of context, lacking even the understanding of Java. But all of them have upvotes, and comments referring to some facts that are not included in questions.

It's very suspicious. It seems that there's a few users from some programming class, that have started using StackOverflow as internal learning help forum.

Is it a separate case, or it's becoming a serious problem here?

Comment: Flag one post for moderator attention, explain in the 'other' option your suspicions and let the diamond-mods sort it out. They have the tools to detect fraud, we don't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters flagged, thanks for suggestion

Comment: he's now going to get banned for asking poor questions

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem

Comment: Hmm I see some interesting things here....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this. As usual with these kind of things there's more going on than meets the eye.

Hopefully I've dealt with the root cause now, but if you see anything more that fits the same pattern or looks like the same person please do flag and/or ping me in chat.

For other moderators I left some notes in the blueroom.