# Effect of question votes

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, search

What are the actual effects of voting on questions? All the documentation I could find just says that voting "moves things up" and "gives people reputation". I get the second part, and I get how voting "moves things up" for answers, but how exactly does voting move things up for questions? Does it make them appear higher on the main page? On in-site search results? On Google search results?

Comment: Which leads to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve

Comment: The answer here seems better than the ones there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The "interesting" tab of SO uses question score to determine the order of questions shown.
- Most views can optionally be sorted by Votes.
- "Relevant" search results incorporates the posts' score
- Readers may be more likely to look at questions with a higher score when they see them, given that they are more likely to be interesting questions
- Very poor scores on your questions in general can result in a question ban for the author
- A low enough score allows for manual immediate deletion of closed questions, and automatic deletion of questions that meet the other given criteria
- It affects reputation (just for completion's sake)
- It can indirectly affect Google search results (increased views and a higher probably of being linked to due to the above reasons can result in more Google Juice), but it won't *directly* affect Google's search results.